# Why is my TreeSet in Java giving me a null pointer exception when I try to add a String?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a project for a Java class, and I can't seem to get past this NullPointerException. The project is a command-line LinkedIn program. One of the aspects I'm implementing is the ability to add a skillset to a user's profile.

I have a LinkedInUser class in which I define a TreeSet to hold these skillsets in the form of Strings entered by the user. I'm using TreeSet, because the assignment requires them to be sorted.

I define the TreeSet in the LinkedInUser class here:

```
private Set<String> skillsets = new TreeSet<>();
```

The action the user takes is defined in the AddSkillsetAction class:

```
String skillset;
    
System.out.println("Enter a skillset to add to your list:");
skillset = scanner.nextLine();

loggedInUser.addSkillset(skillset);
System.out.println(skillset + " has been added to your skillsets.");
```

And the String they enter is passed to the addSkillSet function in the LinkedInUser class:

```
public void addSkillset(String skillset) {
    skillsets.add(skillset);
}
```

I keep getting a NullPointerException on the line:

```
skillsets.add(skillset);
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tested every level up to that line. I even tested the TreeSet inside the addSkillset function with this code:

```
if(skillsets == null) {
   System.out.println("The TreeSet is null.")
}
```

It's telling me the TreeSet is null. I thought instantiating the Set with:

```
private Set<String> skillsets = new TreeSet<>();
```

would actually create an empty TreeSet, instead of it pointing to a null location. Why is my set "skillsets" still pointing to null? What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:
Here are the full classes:

```
package edu.institution.asn2;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class LinkedInUser extends UserAccount implements Comparable<LinkedInUser>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 75648957489235739L;
    private String type;
    private List<LinkedInUser> connections = new ArrayList<>(); 
    private Set<String> skillsets = new TreeSet<>();
    
    public LinkedInUser(String username, String password) {
        super(username, password);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
    
    // Add a connection to user's list
    public void addConnection(LinkedInUser user) throws LinkedInException {
        int index = connections.indexOf(user);
        if (index >= 0) {
            throw new LinkedInException("You are already connected with this user.");
        }
        else {
            connections.add(user);
        }
    }
    
    // Remove a connection from the user's connection list
    public void removeConnection(LinkedInUser user) throws LinkedInException {
        int index = connections.indexOf(user);
        if (index < 0) {
            throw new LinkedInException("You are NOT connected to this user.");
        }
        else {
            connections.remove(index);
        }
    }
    
    // Return a copy of the ArrayList of connections
    public List<LinkedInUser> getConnections() {
        ArrayList<LinkedInUser> copy = new ArrayList<>(connections);
        return copy;
    }
    
    // Return the number of connections
    public int getNumberOfConnections() {
        return connections.size();
    }
    
    // Return the skillsets
    public Set<String> getSkillsets(){
        return skillsets;
    }
    
    // Add a skillset
    public void addSkillset(String skillset) {
        skillsets.add(skillset);
    }
    
    // Remove a skillset
    public void removeSkillset (String skillset) {
        if(skillsets.contains(skillset)){
            skillsets.remove(skillset);
        } else {
            System.out.println(skillset + " is not in your skills list.");
        }
    }
    
    // Override the compareTo function
    @Override
    public int compareTo(LinkedInUser user) {
        int i = this.getUsername().compareToIgnoreCase(user.getUsername());
        return i;
    }

}
```

And the class to add a skillset:

```
package edu.institution.actions.asn7;

import java.util.Scanner;

import edu.institution.ApplicationHelper;
import edu.institution.UserRepository;
import edu.institution.actions.MenuAction;
import edu.institution.asn2.LinkedInUser;

public class AddSkillsetAction implements MenuAction {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Scanner scanner, UserRepository userRepository, LinkedInUser loggedInUser) {
        String skillset;
        
        System.out.println("Enter a skillset to add to your list:");
        skillset = scanner.nextLine();
        
        loggedInUser.addSkillset(skillset);
        System.out.println(skillset + " has been added to your skillsets.");
        
        ApplicationHelper.incrementSkillsetCount(skillset);
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

After I run and try to add a skillset, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.institution.asn2.LinkedInUser.addSkillset(LinkedInUser.java:69)
    at edu.institution.actions.asn7.AddSkillsetAction.process(AddSkillsetAction.java:19)
    at edu.institution.ApplicationController.process(ApplicationController.java:61)
    at edu.institution.LinkedInCLI.main(LinkedInCLI.java:39)
```

LinkedInUser.java:69 is:

```
    skillsets.add(skillset);
```

Comment: Hi @Zimmermr - where is `loggedInUser` assigned a value - that's possibly what the null pointer exception is from.

Comment: loggedInUser is a non-null LinkedInUser passed to the process function. I just added the full code for both functions.

Answer (score 0):

By the way… Your naming is confusing. `String skillset;` should be `String skill`, and `.addSkill` not `.addSkillset`, because you are adding *individual* skills rather than adding a set.

Clarifying your naming may clarify your code. Notice the singular `skill` and plural `skills` naming used in code below.

---

You did not provide enough details to diagnose the problem. But I can show you some example code based on your descriptions.

Your problem may be related to your not properly instantiating the `TreeSet`. Notice in this code that you have a choice of at least two places in which to instantiate:

- On the declaration line of `skills`.
- In the constructor. (Code currently commented-out.)

The `LinkedInUser` class.

```java
package work.basil.linkedin;

import java.util.NavigableSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class LinkedInUser
{
    private String name;
    private NavigableSet < String > skills = new TreeSet <>();

    // Constructor
    public LinkedInUser ( final String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
//        this.skills = new TreeSet <>() ;
    }

    // Modifiers

    public void setName ( String name ) { this.name = name; }

    public void addSkill ( String skill ) { this.skills.add( skill ); }

    // Getters

    public String getName ( ) { return name; }

    public Set < String > getSkills ( ) { return Set.copyOf( this.skills ); }  // Return a unmodifiable copy of the set. (defensive programming)
}
```

For [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), we return a copy of the set. This unmodifiable copy returned by `Set.copyOf` has no order. In some implementations, the order may even change arbitrarily for each iterator. If you want to return an ordered `NavigableSet` instead, do this:

- Change the return type of the method to `NavigableSet`.
- Change the code to pass the instance’s set to the constructor of another set.

```java
public NavigableSet < String > getSkills ( ) { return new TreeSet <>(this.skills ); }
```

Usage.

```java
LinkedInUser alice = new LinkedInUser( "Alice" );
LinkedInUser bob = new LinkedInUser( "Bob" );

alice.addSkill( "Yodeling" );
alice.addSkill( "Tap Dancing" );
bob.addSkill( "Juggling" );

System.out.println( alice.getName() + " does " + alice.getSkills() );
System.out.println( bob.getName() + " does " + bob.getSkills() );

System.out.println( List.of( alice , bob ) );
```

When run.

```
Alice does [Yodeling, Tap Dancing]
Bob does [Juggling]
[LinkedInUser{name='Alice', skills=[Tap Dancing, Yodeling]}, LinkedInUser{name='Bob', skills=[Juggling]}]
```

---

You said:

> I thought instantiating the Set with:
>
> `private Set<String> skillsets = new TreeSet<>();`

Yes, that would indeed instantiate a `TreeSet` object, and store a reference to that set in a variable named `skillsets`. I expect you are placing that code in the wrong location. Again, look at the two locations I suggested earlier in this Answer: on declaration line, or in constructor.